# Finishing off the proof of the Weierstrass Approximation Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, weierstrass-approximation

$\def\R{\mathbf{R}}$
I've so far proved that the Weierstrass Approximation Theorem is true on $[-1.1]$.
That is, a continuous function $f:[-1,1]\to\R$ can be uniformly approximated by polynomials.
The final step is going from this special case to the general case of an arbitrary continuous function with domain $[a,b]$. Earlier in an exercise relating to uniformly approximating the absolute value function on a general interval, starting from a $[-1,1]$ approximation in hand, there was a trick that we used, to let $c=\max{(|a|,|b|)}$. And manipulate the terms using $f(x/c)$. I tried to use that similar trick. (Exercise 6.7.7(b) and 6.7.8(d), Understanding Analysis by Abbott, 2nd Edition for those curious).

*Proof attempt.* Let $f:[a,b]\to\R$ and let $\epsilon>0$.
Let $c=\max(|a|,|b|)$. Now $f(x/c)$ is a function with inputs essentially in $[-1,1]$, so we can use the WAT for $[-1,1]$ to find a polynomial $p$ such that
$$\bigg|p\bigg(\frac{x}{c}\bigg)-f\bigg(\frac{x}{c}\bigg)\bigg|\leq\frac{\epsilon}{c}.$$
Now multiplying both sides by $c$ we get,
$$\bigg|c\cdot p\bigg(\frac{x}{c}\bigg)-c\cdot f\bigg(\frac{x}{c}\bigg)\bigg|\leq\epsilon.$$
Let $q$ be a polynomial on $[a,b]$ defined by
$$q(x):=c\cdot p\bigg(\frac{x}{c}\bigg)$$.
so we have
$$\bigg|q(x)-c\cdot f\bigg(\frac{x}{c}\bigg)\bigg|\leq\epsilon.$$
I'm stuck now.
Am I going in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at $f(\frac x c)$ does not work

Define $F:[-1,1]\to \mathbb R$ by $F(t)=f(a+\frac {(1+t)(b-a)} 2)$. Then $F$ is a continuous function on $[-1,1]$ so there is a polynomial $q$ such that $|F(x)-q(x)|<\epsilon$ for $-1 \leq t \leq 1$. Let $p(x)=q(\frac {2 {(x-a)}} {b-a}-1)$. Can you complete the proof?

Comment: Yep! At first I didn't understand the motivation behind your definition of $F$ and then of $p$, but after realizing that those inner functions are bijections from $[a,b]\leftrightarrow[-1,1]$ I got it, and completed the proof. Really nice. Thanks!